# How to move superponed correlation labels from ggplot geom_cor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The correlation labels are superponed as they both move to same y.lab, is there a way of separating them so they can be both visible?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tibble(
  value = c(0.0019, 0.0014, 0.0016, 0.0013, 0.0013, 0.00139, 0.00079, 0.0029, 0.00135, 0.003291401, 0.00228, 0.00231, 0.00307, 0.00332),
  time = rep(1:7,2),
  variable = c(rep("A",7),rep("B",7)))


ggscatter(df, x = "time", y = "value",
   color = "variable", palette = "jco",
   add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE)+
  stat_cor(aes(color = variable), method = "pearson", label.x = 2, label.y = 0.004)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply some aesthetic to the `label.y=` argument.  You can either do that within your data if feasible (meaning, put it in `aes()` and assign a column name from your dataframe to supply the `label.y` values), or just by sending more than one number.  In this simple case (with two variables), it's probably easiest to specify by sending a vector rather than a single number:

```
ggscatter(df, x = "time", y = "value",
    color = "variable", palette = "jco",
    add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE)+
stat_cor(aes(color = variable),
    method = "pearson",
    label.x = 2, label.y = c(0.0038,0.004))
```

[image]